# Jboss getting sutck while running

Tags: java, jboss, runtime, jboss-4.2.x

I am using jboss-4.2.3.GA.

I face this strange issue only when I start the server from cmd prompt. The execution is getting stuck. Like from the time I execute run.bat, if I have the cmd window open and right click on the window then server continues to work. When I move to other window then it stops. Again I want to open the cmd prompt and click some where on the screen and it resumes.

This happen while running the application also. I need to click on the cmd prompt after making some action in my application.

I am not sure if there is some issue with jboss or some issue with my windows command prompt. Any idea about his will much help.

Comment: Is it possible that you are accidentally clicking in the cmd prompt window? This will pause the process (or rather pause its output, which I think will have the same effect) . See http://superuser.com/questions/459609/what-does-it-do-exactly-if-i-click-in-the-window-of-cmd

Comment: @Disco3 That was help full. I did a change with ref to that post and it works!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the title bar of the cmd windows and choose Properties, select Options tab and select "Quick Edit Mode" and click ok. I don't know what exactly happens when I do that, but it fixed the above issue.